# How do I use the current sound out as an audio input in Quartz Composer?

Tags: macos, audio, visualization, visualizer, quartz-composer

If I want to build a spectrum visualizer of what's currently playing on my speakers (not the line in) what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install [Wiretap Anywhere](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wta/) from Ambrosia Software.

Wiretap allows you to take any audio outputs from applications and route them to a virtual audio input which you can use in Quartz Composer, or any other OS X application that uses a hardware input.